# Want to continue test cases after fail - currently using assertEquals in selenium RC/1.0

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc

I am using `assertEquals` in selenium RC to handle the alerts, but if I am using it and it fails, the test cases getting stopped. I want to continue my test cases after failing.

Secondly, when I am using `verifyEquals`, it's getting pass whether the test cases pass or fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the Assert in a try/catch block.  In the catch block set some boolean caught error variable to true.  Assuming that you want the test to ultimately fail as the last step assert that the caught error boolean is false.

Comment: Mike, I am trying to capture the status of all test cases in excel sheet, for this I need the whole code to run. If also I use the assertEquals in try box, it will directly terminate from there, and show the message under catch block, and further codes will not get proceed.

Comment: try {
    assertEquals("message", someObject.getValue1(), expectedValue1); 
} catch(AssertionError ae) {
    caughtException = true; }

If you don't fail the test then reflect the failure in the Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with try and catch block like given below -

```
try
{
assertEquals .....
}catch(Exception e){}
```

In this case the code inside try block will execute and if any exception is thrown then the test cases continues to run.
You can use below code in case of assertion errors. In both cases your test case execution will continue.

```
try{
asset statements
}catch(AssertionError e){}
```

Comment: Anuja, it will not help, as we will put assert it will directly so as fail, and will not proceed further. see the comment I have provided below

Comment: This works for me . try once to execute your test suite.